# In Android Studio, a button specified as a drawable oval shows as circular on the design screen but comes out square when run

Tags: android

In Android Studio, a button specified as a drawable oval shows as circular on the design screen but comes out square when run, on either a simulated or a real android device.

[image: ScreenShot of the phenomenon]

The image shows activity_clickerscreen.xml. TextView hoopWin2bk describes the bottom-right-hand yellow outer circle, which runs correctly on the simulated device. Button hoopWin2 describes the bottom right-hand red inner disc, which shows correctly on the design screen but comes out square on the simulated device.
Can anyone suggest a solution?

This is the code for button_shape_2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
```

I have found that the problem is resolved if I remove/comment out the following kotlin code in Clickerscreen.kt

```
  if(priSec==false){
            score1bk.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_brown))
            score1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green))
            p1text.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_brown))
       //     hoopWin1bk.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.brown))
            hoopWin1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green))
            score2bk.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.off_white))
            score2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_pink))
            p2text.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.off_white))
       //     hoopWin2bk.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
            hoopWin2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_pink))
            hoopWin1.setText(resources.getString(R.string.hoopwin1green))
            hoopWin2.setText(resources.getString(R.string.hoopwin2pink))
        }else{     // leave TextView colours as set by activity_clickerscreen.xml
                    // but set button colours
            hoopWin1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_blue))
            hoopWin2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red))
            hoopWin1.setText(resources.getString(R.string.hoopwin1blue))
            hoopWin2.setText(resources.getString(R.string.hoopwin2red))
        }
```

so the problem is linked to setting the button colours in the kotlin code.

Comment: Please share button_shape_2 XML

Comment: this issue might occur for not using `size` tag in `@drawable/button_shape2`. please share its code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try code as mentioned below for button

kotlin

```
hoopWin2.outlineProvider = ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND
hoopWin2.clipToOutline = true
```

java

```
hoopWin2.setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND);
hoopWin2.setClipToOutline(true);
```

Comment: I have added some Kotlin code which pinpoints the problem to setting the button colours in kotlin.